# Group policy folder redirection not applying when using advanced setting

Tags: group-policy, folder-redirection

I'm trying to set-up folder redirection using group policy with the advanced setting, i.e. only apply if the user is in a specified group. The overall policy is applying fine (as confirmed using gpresult) but the folder redirection itself isn't applying:

[image]

The user is definitely a member of the group. As a test, I turned on folder redirection of Saved Games using Basic, i.e. everyone is redirected if the policy applies to them and bizarrely, the Documents redirection also started working.

This is either a weird bug or I'm missing something. Folder redirection using advanced setting only applies if there is one or more other folder redirections using basic.

It makes no sense but if I put the "Saved games" basic setting back to "Not configured", the Documents redirection also stops working.

Comment: A workaround would be a separate policy which is targeted overall to a specific user group. However, in general, I like to keep the number of group policies to a minimum